# JPA EJBException id is null on EntityManager.persist()

Tags: jpa, constraints, one-to-one

I have the following model objects in an Java EE application:

**Person.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_person")
    private Integer idPerson;

    // some other fields (name, birthdate, etc.)

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "person")
    private User user;

    // Constructors, get/set, etc.
```

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id_person") // Because it's a FK
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer idPerson;

    // some other fields (username, etc)

    @JoinColumn(name = "id_person", referencedColumnName = "id_persona", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @OneToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Person person;

    // Constructors, get/set, etc.
```

The `ManagedBean` is as follows:

**UserController.java**

```
@ManagedBean(name = "usuarioController")
@ViewScoped
public class UsuarioController implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7002352152240769558L;

    @EJB
    private UserFacadeLocal userEJB;
    private Person person;
    private User user;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        person = new Person();
        user = new User();
    }

    // getters/setters

    public void register(){
    try{
        this.user.setPerson(person);
        this.person.setUser(user); // BreakPoint 1
        userEJB.create(user);
        // Success Message
        } catch (Exception e){  // Breakpoint 2
            // Error message
        }
    }
```

`User` and `Person` objects are filled with a `<h:form>` in a JSF page. Debugging the program I can see that in `Breakpoint 1` the fields `person.idPerson` and `user.idPerson` are both NULL. In `Breakpoint 2` `person.idPerson` has a value but `user.idPerson` is still NULL. The caught `Exception` is an `EJBException` (according with the variables description in NetBeans) and the message is:

```
Error Code: 1048
Call: INSERT INTO user (id_person, ...) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [5 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(model.User[ idPerson=null ])
...stacktrace...
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'id_person' cannot be null
```

I can't find where the problem is. I'm using JavaEE 7 with JDK 1.8, JSF 2.2 and EclipseLink2.5.2 as a Persistence Provider.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no entity with a table name of User.

Comment: Sorry, it's a translation error, must be `user` where you read `usuario` (user in spanish). Usually I "translate" the variables name for a better "international understanding" of the variable's purpose. I'll change it right now

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted to use same PK for both `Person` and `User` table.

Update your entities to use `@MapsId` annotation, as below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_person")
    private Integer idPerson;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "person")
    User user;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [idPerson=" + idPerson + ", user=" + user.person.idPerson + "]";
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_person")
    Integer idPerson;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_person", referencedColumnName = "id_person", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @MapsId
    Person person;
}
```

And while saving, set the `Person` field in the `User` object as:

```
Person person = new Person();
User user = new User();
person.user = user;
user.person = person;
userEJB.create(person); or userEJB.create(user);
```